# hide id or title in url for secret information

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to pass id or title with url for get them to other component but i dont need to show id or title in url

```
http://localhost:4200/#/news/comment/44/list
```

i need my url like this but it have my information

```
http://localhost:4200/#/news/comment/list
```

and this is my routerLink :

```
<a mat-icon-button [matTooltip]="'TOOLTIP.LIKE' | translate"
                        [routerLink]="['/news/comment/like',row.id,'list']">
```

how can i do this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you should use a service. In this service you store your selection in a subject e.g. *BehaviourSubject* from rxjs and then query the selection from that service in your child component.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private mySubject: BehaviourSubject<number> = new BehaviourSubject<number>(null);
  myObservable$: Observable<number> = this.mySubject.asObservable();  // <-- use this observable for getting the value

  setValue(id: number) {
    this.mySubject.next(id);
  }
}
```